# MDX Calculated Measure for Customer and Route by Day

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

I'm working with a cube that needs a new calculated measure and I'm having a difficult time getting the MDX right.

The scenario that I'm looking to measure is a count of days where for a given Customer (by Customer Name) and Delivery Route (also on the Customer Dimension) the total sales amount is greater than 0.

The date hierarchy is fairly straightforward.

- Date > Year > Month > Day

In the customer dimension, we are not going to be using a hierarchy.

- customer name
- delivery route

On the measures, we only really care about total sales

- total sales

So, I've tried a little bit of everything, but I'm not sure I'm approaching the problem in the right way and that could be that I'm less familiar with MDX.

Here's a sample of data and what my end goal would be.

[image: Sample Data Set]

What I've tried to get there has been the following (however, nothing has provided what I need).

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[count deliveries]
AS
COUNT(FILTER(DESCENDANTS([Date].[Calendar].[Year].&[2013],2), [Measures].[total sales] > 0) )
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[total sales]
, [Measures].[count deliveries]} ON 0
, NON EMPTY ([Customer].[Customer Name]
, {DESCENDANTS([Date].[Calendar].&[2013],2)}) ON 1
FROM [Sales]
```

**THE END GOAL**

I would like to have this added as a calculated member to the cube and not just in query format.  Any help would be appreciated!